# Difference between site.master main.master

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is the Difference between site.master vs main.master.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference is the name.

Both are master pages - one is called `site` the other `main`. You can have more than one `master` page in a site - different content pages can use different `master` pages.